# Blank lines in multilingual references using biblatex-option "babel=other"

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex` with the option "babel=other" in order to get a multilingual bibliography. Unfortunately there occure blank lines between my bibliography entries, below entries that almost fill a line. If I switch off the option `babel=other` the unwanted blank lines disaprear, but the bibliography isn't multilingual anymore.

Here's my code, which results in one unwanted blank line:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}    
\usepackage[style=authoryear,babel=other]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibliographie}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here's the content of the file `bibliographie.bib`
used above. It's located in the same directory as the `tex` file.

```
@Book{Davidson,
author      = {James Davidson},
title       = {{Stochastic Limit Theory}},
year        = {1994},
address     = {Oxford},
publisher       = {Oxford University Press},
hyphenation     = {english}
}

@article{Ghysels,
title       = {{On stable factor structures in the pricing of risk: Do time-varying betas help or hurt?}},
author      = {E. Ghysels}, 
year            = {1998},
journal     = {Journal of Finance},
volume      = {53},
pages           = {549--573},
hyphenation     = {english}
}

@Book{Breiman,
author      = {Leo Breiman  },
title       = {{Probability}},
year        = {1968},
address     = {Reading (Massachusetts) and Menlo Park (California) and London and Don Mills (Ontario)},
publisher       = {Addison-Wesley Publishing Company},
hyphenation     = {english}
}

@Book{Goos,
author      = {Gerhard Goos},
title       = {{Vorlesungen über Informatik}},
volume      = {1},
year        = 2000,
address     = {Berlin and Heidelberg and New York},
publisher       = {Springer-Verlag},
edition     = {3},
isbn        = {3-540-67270-2},
hyphenation     = {ngerman}
}
```

Could anyone help me? I would be happy.